# TCategorybutton is showing a chevron, how do I remove it?

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-10.4-sydney

I'm working with the [`TSplitView` demo](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Sydney/en/VCL.SplitView_Sample), and have found that the `TCategoryButton` will sometimes show a chevron, sometimes not. I do not currently want it, but don't know how to turn it off.

Comment: The `Top` property of `catMenuItems` is -20 in the original sample, effectively hiding the chevron.

Comment: That sounds right, because it started appearing when I was playing with alignment. Thanks so much.